# How can I get multiple values from arrayfun in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the following sample code.

```
clear
clc
a = 1:1000;
b = linspace(100,200,1000);     
x1 = arrayfun( @(v,w) fminsearch(@(x) (x(1)-v).^2 + (x(2)-w).^2, [1;1]), a, b, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

and x1 returns 1*1000 cells and each of the cells gives me the minimizer v and w that minimizes the objection function given v and w.

However, I want to get 2*1000 double instead of 1*1000 cells.

Is there any way I can get x1 as 2*1000?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `f` is not used, and the line that computes `x` seems irrelevant to the question. These things just confuse everyone trying to help you. Could you please read again [mre], and [edit] your question accordingly? Finally, please explain what you are trying to accomplish with the code, and what extra information you want in the array so it can grow  from 1x1000 to 2x1000. Do you just want to add empty cells? Or is there something specific you want in those cells?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comments. I changed the code accordingly. Each cell in 1 x 1000 gives me two values(x(1) and x(2)) and I just wanted to have it as 2 x 1000 double.

Comment: x1 = cell2mat(x1);